# How to read one line with urllib.request

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib

I am trying to read one line of a web page with the `urllib.request` module.

I have tried `readline()`, `readlines()` and  `read()` but I cannot make it read just one line.

How can I do this?

I am just trying to read the 581th line from [python.org](https://www.python.org).

My script at the moment is:

```
import urllib.request

get_page = urllib.request.urlopen('https://www.python.org')
x = int('581')
get_ver = get_page.readline(x)

print("Currant Versions Are: ", get_ver)
```

And the result of this is:

```
Currant Versions Are:  b'<!doctype html>\n'
```

The result is always the same even if I change the number.

So how do I just read the 581th line?

Comment: What makes you think the argument to `readline` is the line number to read? Also why are you relying on the content being on a specific line?

Comment: If you want line 574, you have to read and discard the first 573 lines.  No way around it.

Comment: @JohnGordon technically if the server accepts range requests you can send a range header for a certain byte range of the content in a get request... but yeah...

Comment: @jonrsharpe  `read()` reads the whole webpage, `readlines()` shows the same as `read()`, the only one that shows one line is `readline()`.  The reason I want a specific line is because I want to read the content off that line only not the rest of the page.

Comment: Yes, but it's not at all clear 1. why you think it's a good idea to rely on the line number never changing or 2. why you thought `readline(574)` would achieve that. Your question makes no sense. Use an HTML parser, at least then simple format changes won't break your code.

Comment: @jonrsharpe `next(islice(iter(get_page.readline, ''), 573, None))`? *shrugs*

Comment: @jonrsharpe  The idea is for my own webpage!  I have used python.org because my webpage is not online yet and since I am going to maintain it I can keep it on the same line.  I will research about an html parser though.

Comment: Don't you already know what's on your own webpage? Please give some more context, it seems less and less likely that an answer to your question (thanks @JonClements!) will actually solve your problem.

Comment: @jonrsharpe  Not all webpages are static (take Stack Overflow for example) yes they change lines but I have accounted for that and yes I know whats on my webpage.  This is part of an application I am trying to make so that users (who do not know the content) will see the content immediately after opening the application rather than making them open the browser, type in the address, find the correct page, scroll down to the relevant part (you get the idea, for simplicity) and soon as it changes just repeat the process again.

Comment: Why don't you run the desktop application and web page from the same *API*, then, rather than have the former parse the latter? That allows you to update one without worrying about whether it breaks the other, and it's easier and less error prone to parse e.g. JSON than HTML.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Good idea, I could still use Python and make it easier to maintain.  Also I believe there is a module for JSON.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you are reading up to **limit** of 574 bytes and not the line 574.

that way you can get the `n-th` line number while trying to minimize the amount of data read from the server (check out [http range request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Range_requests) if you need better performance):

```
import urllib.request
from itertools import islice

get_page = urllib.request.urlopen('https://www.python.org')

def get_nth_line(resp, n):
    i = 1
    while i < n:
        resp.readline()
        i += 1
    return resp.readline()

print(get_nth_line(get_page, 574))
```

outputs:

```
b'<p>Latest: <a href="/downloads/release/python-362/">Python 3.6.2</a> - <a href="/downloads/release/python-2713/">Python 2.7.13</a></p>\n'
```

## Suggestions

1. use [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) for http requests instead of `urllib`

`requests.get('http://www.python.org').read()`

2. use regex or [bs4](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) for parsing and extracting the version of python

### Requests & Regex Example

```
import re, requests

resp = requests.get('http://www.python.org')
# regex might need adjustments
ver_regex = re.compile(r'<a href\="/downloads/release/python\-2\d+/">(.*?)</a>')
py2_ver = ver_regex.search(resp.text).group(1)
print(py2_ver)
```

outputs:

```
Python 2.7.13
```

Comment: *"without reading the whole response"* - I don't think that is true.

Comment: correct, its the best you can do at application level AFAIK (updated) without http range request

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to do it using `readlines()`.

Here is the working script:

```
import urllib.request

get_page = urllib.request.urlopen('https://www.python.org')
get_ver = get_page.readlines()

print("Currant Versions Are: ", get_ver[580])
```

It wasn't working because the `readlines()` value must be a list.  Also it is 580 not 581 because the first line counts as 0.